# How to use indirect configuration within an SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

1. I created an environment variable
2. Created a package configurations, chose indirect XML Configuration and select the environemnt i created
3. Now Manually created the connection to the database

So, now how do i tell BIDS to use the connection from step **2** instead of the one from step **3**?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that shows how this can be achieved. The detailed process with screenshots are documented here at [**this link**](http://learnbycoding.com/2011/07/saving-ssis-xml-configuration-file-path-in-an-environment-variable/). Following is a text-only version of the same available in the link.

1. Before we open BIDS, we need to create an Environment Variable. Click Windows Start button and click Control Panel. On the `Control Panel`, click `System and Security`. On the System and Security window, click `System`. On the System window’s left side navigation, click `Advanced system settings`.
2. On the System Properties dialog, make sure Advanced tab is selected. On the Advanced tab, click `Environment Variables…` button. On the Environment Variables dialog, there will be two sections of Environment Variables, one **user** based and the other **system** based. We will create new System based environment variable so that the variable is common to the machine and not per user basis So, click on the New… button under the System variables section. On the New System Variable dialog, set the Variable name to `SSIS Indirect Configuration` and set the Variable value to `C:\temp\SSIS_Configurations.dtsConfig`. On the Environment Variables dialog, click OK to close the dialog. Click OK to close the System Properties dialog.
3. Now, open BIDS create an SSIS package. If you had BIDS open, you need to close and re-open the BIDS so that the Environment Variable changes are correctly reflected within BIDS IDE.
4. On the SSIS package, create two variables namely **Country** and **State**. Set the variable Country with value `Canada` and the variable State to `Alberta`.
5. On the packages, place a Script Task on the Control Flow and name it as `Display variable’s value`. Double-click on the Script task to open the Scrip Task Editor. On the Script section, click Edit Script… button. The script task code will appear in VSTA editor. Replace the `Main()` method with the code provided under **Script Task Code** section. Close the VSTA editor. Click OK to close the Script Task Editor.
6. If you execute the package now, you will get the output **Canada – Alberta** because those are the values the variables are assigned with.
7. Now, the package configurations have to be created. It is possible to create one Environment variable for each variable present in the package. In my opinion, that will quickly get out of hand. I prefer to first create an XML configuration file and save it to a local folder. Then, I will change the file path to match the path used in the Environment variable. The following steps explain this process.
8. Click on the package. Select SSIS menu and then then click `Package Configurations…`. On the Package Configurations Organizer dialog, check Enable package configurations and click Add… button. On the Select Configuration Type wizard, select XML configuration file as the Configuration type. Select Specify configuration settings directly radio button and provide the path `C:\temp\Package Configuration.dtsConfig` as the Configuration file name. Yes, this path doesn’t match the path in the environment but we will rename it shortly. Click Next > button. On Select Properties to Export, I would like to save only the values of the variables, so expand the Variables node and check only the Value Properties of the variables Country and State. There is a separate node available for connection string, which will allow us to save the connection strings to the configuration file. Click Next > button. On Completing the Wizard step, provide the Configuration name value as `Package Configuration` and click Finish.
9. Now, we need to create the indirect configuration. On the Package Configuration Organizer, click Add… button. On the Select Configuration Type wizard, select XML configuration file as the Configuration type. This time select the radio button Configuration location is stored in an environment variable. Select the Environment variable `SSIS Indirect Configuration`. This is the variable that we just created. Click Next > button. On Completing the Wizard step, provide the Configuration name value as `Indirect Configuration File` and click Finish. On the Package Configurations Organizer dialog, select the configuration Indirect Configuration File and click the Up arrow on the right-hand side to move this configuration ahead of the Package Configuration.
10. When there are two configurations with the same set of variables, the second configuration in the list will take precedence. In other words, package will use only the values present in the second configuration. Copy the file `C:\temp\Package Configuration.dtsConfig` and create a new configuration file named `C:\temp\SSIS_Configurations.dtsConfig` to match the path provided in the Environment Variable.
11. The file Package Configuration.dtsConfig contains the values **Canada** for `Country` and **Alberta** for `State`. The newly created file SSIS_Configurations.dtsConfig also contains the same values. We will change the value in the SSIS_Configurations.dtsConfig  as  **United States** for `Country` and **California** for `State`.
12. If we run the package now, the values from the file SSIS_Configurations.dtsConfig   will be used because the Indirect Configuration File is second on the list of Package Configurations. So, the values in the Indirect Configuration File will have higher precedence.
13. Even if we delete the `Package Configuration` file named **Package Configuration.dtsConfig**, the package will continue to run correctly using the Indirect configuration file that uses the configuration file **SSIS_Configurations.dtsConfig**. This method helps to create only one Environment Variable that can tie back to an XML configuration file which can contain many SSIS package variables. This avoids creating one Environment variable for each package variable. We can switch the location of the package configuration file without having to change the package in anyway. All we need to do is change the value in the Environment Variable to the new path. This change will automatically reflect in the package.

Hope that helps.

**Script Task Code:**

**C#** code that can be used only in **`SSIS 2008 and above`**.

```
public void Main()
{
    Variables varCollection = null;

    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::Country");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::State");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} - {1}", varCollection["User::Country"].Value, varCollection["User::State"].Value));

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: The config filenames must be different. You cannot use same filename for both settings

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

Step 1) Create an environment variable (in my case called CONFIGDB) on each server you will be running packages.  The Value of the CONFIGDB is the connection string for the Configuration database for that server.

Step 2) In your package, manually create a connection to your configuration database.

Step 3) Create a package configuration (environment variable type) pointing to the environment variable and configuring the db connection object connection string (this way when the package loads, the environment variable overrides the manually set connection string).

Step 4) Create any additional package configurations as Sql Server type and point them to the database connection defined in step 2.  (this will allow the configuration items to be set to different values for each environment in which you run ssis.)

Step 5) Go to your other environments where this package may run and insert/modify the configuration items in that DB for that environment (i.e. one for Dev, one for TEST and one for Prod).